# Twilio VirtualENV Import Failures

Tags: python, virtualenv, twilio

I am new to virtual environments and seem to be missing something simple.

I have a fresh virtual environment in which I cannot import some modules from Twilio. I activated the environment (`source TextingENV/bin/activate`) and used `pip install twilio` to install the latest Twilio. I can launch python and run `import twilio` with no problem. But I cannot do the following:

```
>>> from twilio import TwilioRestException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name TwilioRestException

>>> from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name TwilioRestClient
```

I have checked the version of twilio in both my main environment and this virtual one and they are both 6.0.0 (`pip freeze | grep twilio` while virtualenv is active and not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In version 6 of the [Twilio Python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python), [`TwilioRestException` can be found in `twilio.base.exceptions`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/7b56015214ad486c616cdff9b5c59ab4ee6f2ac8/twilio/base/exceptions.py). So you want:

```
>>> from twilio.base.exceptions import TwilioRestException
```

Comment: Thank you @philnash. And `from twilio.rest import Client` seems to replace `from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient`. Do you know why the old commands work in the native environment but not the virtual? That still has me confused.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, I'm not really a Python developer so I don't know virtual environments well. Sorry!